# Node field not sanitize on render

Tags: theming, nodes, security

I have a form for users who want to add new content on my Drupal 8 website.
I render node field on a twig template :

`{{ node_field_title.value }}`

But field are not sanitized by Drupal. Is it the normal behaviour ?

--> If the title is `<script>alert('XSS problem!')</script>` the script will be executed.

Drupal 8 documentation says : 'The Twig theme engine now auto escapes everything by default. That means that every string printed from a Twig template (e.g. anything between {{ }}) gets automatically sanitized if no filters are used.'

Comment: Do you see the script tag on the screen? Then it is auto escaped and can't be executed.

Comment: In case it is executed then post the entire code what you put into the variable and what else the template contains which might be relevant for autoescaping.

Comment: The value of the field is :  `<script>alert('XSS problem')</script>`. The script is exexcuted and if i click on 'OK' to close the alert windows, i can see the script written on the page.

Comment: Please add the information as asked to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Ok, It's because of a breadcrumb block who render my field_title. with a `|raw` . Not a good idea.. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no autoescaping, at least for Drupal 8.7.3 which the version I tested.
For example:

```
{{ "<div>Is this escaped?</div>" }}
{{ "<script>alert('NOO!');</script> "}}
```

These lines are not escaped by default. However:

```
{{ "<div>Is this escaped?</div>"|escape }}
{{ "<script>alert('NOO!');</script>"|escape}}
```

These are escaped, so better be safe than sorry and use `|escape` for the input you're getting from your users.

Comment: Static expressions are not auto escaped, only variables or objects.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying